# Is there a way to render an HTML page from Ruby?

Tags: html, ruby, file, browser

I am developing an application that takes in the address of a web page and generates an HTML file with the source of that page.  I have successfully generated the file.  I can't figure out how to launch that file in a new tab.  Here

This is running in Repl.it, a web-based code editor.  Here's what I have:

```
def run
require 'open-uri'
puts "enter a URL and view the source"
puts "don't include the https:// at the beginning"
url = gets.chomp
fh =  open("https://"+url)
html = fh.read
puts html
out_file = File.new("out.html", "w")
out_file.puts(html)
out_file.close
run
end
```

Then I'm running that code.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question but what I do see is an infinite loop here where `run` is recursively calling itself ad infinitum. If you wish to actually open a webpage in a browser you will need 1) a browser; 2) a gem like `selenium` that will open said page in the specified browser. Given that this is running on repl.it #1 is going to be nearly impossible as it would require access to the server on which this code is running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you just want to save html of site and open new file in your browser.

You can do it this way (I use Firefox).

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse('https://bla-bla-bla.netlify.com/')
response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)

file_name = 'out.html'

File.write(file_name, response.body)

system("firefox #{file_name}")
```

Note: Keep in mind that site owners often block parsers, so you may have to use `torify`.

Now check the file

```
$ cat out.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Bla-bla-bla</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Bla-bla</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything worked out.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to open this file locally in your computer, I would perform a `system` call.

For example on my macOS the following would open the HTML page on my default browser:

```rb
system("open #{out_file.path}")
```

If you want to supply the rendered HTML to other users in your network then you will need a HTTP server, I suggest [Sinatra](http://sinatrarb.com/) to start with.

Comment: system runs a file if it's exe, for an example system('notepad.exe') opens a notepad